# Method does not execute when boolean parameter has a value of false

Tags: codefluent

I have isolated the problem to the following lines of code in the BOM method that calls the stored procedure:

```
        if ((includeAgeSeventeenAndUnder == CodeFluentPersistence.DefaultBooleanValue))
        {
            return null;
        }
        if ((includeAgeEighteenAndOver == CodeFluentPersistence.DefaultBooleanValue))
        {
            return null;
        }
```

Because CodeFluentPersistence.DefaultBooleanValue equals False. Anytime a parameter of false is passed to the method, the method exits and returns null. How can I prevent this?

Comment: what are includeAgeSeventeenAndUnder and includeAgeEighteenAndOver set to?

Comment: You can add `cfom:checkDefaultValue="false"` at parameter level to remove the check in the BOM.

Comment: @meziantou - Your approach is best. I added it to my answer.

Comment: @Will Evers - I work for a non-profit and the method is used for a report that is required for one of our grants. Most of the data in the report needs to be broken down by age. When I need to get data for a section of the report for 17 and under, I set includeAgeSeventeenAndUnder to true and includeAgeEighteenAndOver to false. When I need data for 18 and over I do the reverse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it working by setting the modeNullable to true.

```
<cf:method name="Load">
  <cf:body text="LOADONE(date  startDate, date endDate, bool includeAgeSeventeenAndUnder, bool includeAgeEighteenAndOver,int sisProgramId) RAW  " rawText="This has been deleted because it is not relevent to question" language="tsql" />
  <cf:parameter typeName="bool" name="includeAgeSeventeenAndUnder" modelNullable="True" />
  <cf:parameter typeName="bool" name="includeAgeEighteenAndOver" modelNullable="True" />
</cf:method>
```

Meziantou suggestion is actually preferable since I really don't want the parameters to be nullable. The below snippet demonstrates the correct way to disable the default value check.

```
<cf:method name="Load">
  <cf:body text="LOADONE(date  startDate, date endDate, bool includeAgeSeventeenAndUnder, bool includeAgeEighteenAndOver,int sisProgramId) RAW  " rawText="This has been deleted because it is not relevent to question" language="tsql" />
  <cf:parameter typeName="bool" cfom:checkDefaultValue="false" name="includeAgeSeventeenAndUnder" modelNullable="False" />
  <cf:parameter typeName="bool" cfom:checkDefaultValue="false" name="includeAgeEighteenAndOver" modelNullable="False" />
</cf:method>
```